# Optional props arrow function

Tags: reactjs

I would like to make a generic component. For this I would like to be able to pass optional parameter to the props. I use to make it by using interface in typescript, but this project is in pure react. Is there a way to do something like typescript to make parameters optional ? The way I used to do in typescript is like that

```js
interface buttonProps {
    title: string,
    color?: string
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All props are optional unless you define PropTypes and mark them `isRequired`.

[Typechecking with Proptypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes)

Example:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const buttonPropTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired, // required
  color: PropTypes.string,            // optional
};

...

Button.propTypes = propTypes;

export default Button;
```